# How do you avoid rebuilding the container for every code change when using IntelliJ IDEA to develop a Cloud Run service locally?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-intellij

I'm pretty new to IntelliJ (and Docker) so please excuse me if this question is inherently daft - I feel like I must be missing something.

I'm using IDEA Ultimate to develop a Cloud Run service (in node.js) which has to be built as a Docker container. I can deploy that locally, which is a bit faster than uploading every incremental build to Google, but it still seems bizarre that I have to spend a minute and a half rebuilding the entire container every time I want to change a line of code.

Outside a container, I could just save an edited source file and restart node (when a restart is even needed; much of my app is client-side code which node just serves as static files). I feel like once the Docker container exists, IDEA should similarly be able to deploy updated source files "into" it (and restart node if needed, probably automatically using nodemon) rather than rebuilding the whole thing.

I've looked at setting a Docker bind mount to map the in-container app folder to my external project folder, but the IDEA run configuration I'm using for local deployment (Cloud Code:Cloud Run:Run Locally) doesn't seem to provide any field for supplying additional arguments to docker run. Docker Target and Docker Environment are there, but the other options that appear in the Docker:Dockerfile run configuration, including bind mounts, aren't available.

I tried creating a dummy Docker:Dockerfile configuration with a bind mount specified, then copied the relevant  from the saved .xml copy of that to a Cloud Run configuration, but that had no visible effects (it was a bit of a long shot, given I have no real idea how the xml is parsed).

Meanwhile, I'm a bit puzzled also that when I step in to the Docker container via a terminal, the app code isn't accessible in the file system location mentioned (as WORKDIR) in the Dockerfile (which is /usr/src/app) - that folder doesn't even exist; the files do exist in the container, but only in Docker's overlay2 folders. This probably reflects my crude grasp of how Docker works, but it seems like it might be interfering with setting a bind mount to that location.

The Cloud Run run configuration actually starts by launching Minikube, so with a bit more reading I'm starting to wonder whether what I actually need is not a Docker bind mount but a skaffold file sync directive. It looks like that would go in skaffold.yaml, but there isn't one; from the build output, Cloud Code generates a temporary file for the skaffold config.

It would be useful to know what a given run configuration does under the hood - maybe then I could create an entirely custom one that recapitulates what the Cloud Run:Run Locally config does, but with the additional step of adding a bind mount and/or file sync rule.

Am I barking up the wrong tree entirely? Is there a much more straightforward way to achieve this?

Comment: Docker's standard model is in fact that the code is built into an immutable image, and you need to rebuild the image if any of the code changes.  It sounds like you have a working local Node environment; I'd use that for day-to-day development and only bring Docker into the picture for integration testing and deployment.

Comment: @DavidMaze I appreciate that's Docker's general premise, but I don't think it's a hard rule; the [Docker dev best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/dev-best-practices/) say that "One case where it is appropriate to use bind mounts is during development, when you may want to mount your source directory or a binary you just built into your container."

I've noticed now that the container I can see in Docker Desktop (cloud-run-dev-internal) isn't actually the one I built. Possibly there's some nesting involved with minikube, so I may need two mounts to reach the physical host...